# from iOS to Android: Some beginner's questions

Tags: java, android, ios, cocoa-touch

OK I've spent a lot of time working with the iOS SDK, and now i'm porting my app to Android with Eclipse. There are just a few basic things I would like to know that I can't seem to find online:

1. What is the equivalent of `UIImageView`? I have tried my hand at `ImageView`, but even in XML it seems nearly impossible to just resize the thing!
2. What is the equivalent of `presentModalViewController`, and how do I implement the new java and xml files into my project?

Thanks for your help, it seems much harder to get started with Android than it did with iOS!

Comment: [Best Way to start Android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, UIImageView: ImageView are same and you can resize it using ImageView.setWidth(XX),  ImageView.setHeight(XX)

2) For presentModalViewController you have to write the custom animation to make it happen.

Answer (score 2):

@Samir's implied response of "start from the beginning" is correct, but to answer your specific questions:

UIImageView: [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

The closest thing to presentModalViewController that I use is [AlertBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

In my very person opinion, Android way harder to set up and a little easier to code. I started with iOS and now do both. The hardest part is getting used to a different workflow. Think of the XML as equivalent to the Interface Builder step, and then the Activity as the controller code.